# Android onCreateOptionsMenu is never called so the menu isn't being displayed

Tags: android, menu, android-appcompat, android-search

I want to have a search bar in my menu toolbar, but when I navigate to the activity, the menu is never created because onCreateOptionsMenu is never called. I'm extending AppCompatActivity

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_search, menu);
    final SearchView searchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(menu.findItem(R.id.action_search));
    SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(SEARCH_SERVICE);
    searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));

    return true;
}
```

Menu:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item android:id="@+id/action_search"
          android:title="@string/search"
          android:icon="@drawable/ic_search_black_36dp"
          app:showAsAction ="ifRoom|collapseActionView"
          app:actionViewClass ="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView" />

</menu>
```

Comment: @Pavneet_Singh I've also tried that and it does not work

Comment: then you should post the complete code so that folks around can test it

Comment: i think you are using toobar and you didn't set it as the main actionBar

Comment: @OussemaAroua yes that was my problem! Thank you so much :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is probably on your `AndroidManisfest.xml` file. With the following default code I get the `onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)` method loaded:

AndroidManisfest.xml:

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

MainActivity.java:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        Log.d("BugFix","nothing");
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_search, menu);
        final SearchView searchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(menu.findItem(R.id.action_search));
        SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(SEARCH_SERVICE);
        searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));

        return true;
    }
}
```

activity_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.el_greeko.exampleproject.MainActivity">

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

And the rest is your information given, with menu.search.xml in res/menu/

Btw. I suggest to read the instructions in the webpage of the 
[Search dialog](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/search-dialog.html). It may give you also a better solution for your search activity.

Comment: I appreciate the time you took to write out an answer, but Oussema found my problem. I just needed to set my toolbar as my main actionBar